# How to provide initial data to django form wizard?

Tags: python, django, django-formwizard, urlconf

According to the form wizard docs, the initial data should be a static dict. But is it possible to provide initial data dynamically?

Here is my situation:

```
 def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
    context = super(debugRegistrationWizard, self).get_context_data(form=form, **kwargs)
    email = InvitationKey.objects.get_key_email(self.kwargs['invitation_key'])
    context.update({'invitation_key': self.kwargs['invitation_key']})
    return context
```

The email is what I want for initial data in step0, but I can only get this email in get_context_data method. How can I do that?

By the way: if the urlconf for formwizard.as_view accept argument like:

```
url(r'^registration/(?P<invitation_key>\w+)$', debugRegistrationWizard.as_view(FORMS)),
```

does it mean I have to pass a variable to my form's action attributes, because otherwise when I submit the form, I will get a not found url error.

Answer (score 6):

You can override the method `get_form_initial`

```
def get_form_initial(self, step):
    initial = self.initial_dict.get(step, {})
    if step == 42:
        email = InvitationKey.objects.get_key_email(self.kwargs['invitation_key'])
        initial.update({'email': email})
    return initial
```

Ref: https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html#formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.get_form_initial

Answer (score 3):

The [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16494842/39155) is almost there. You *do* need to override `get_form_initial`, but `self.kwargs` (at least in the latest version of Django formtools) does **not** contain GET or POST parameters of the request.

The solution is pretty straightforward: just reference the values from the request directly, since `self.request` is an attribute right on the wizard.

```
def get_form_initial(self, step):
    initial = self.initial_dict.get(step, {})
    invitation_key = self.request.GET.get("invitiation_key")
    email = InvitationKey.objects.get_key_email(invitation_key)
    initial.update({'email': email})
    return initial
```

Comment: Where is context coming from and where is initial being used?

Comment: No idea, but just fixed it up :)